# OOP - Handle class

Tags: oop, class, matlab

I came about the term `handle class` in object-oriented programming in `Matlab`. What do we mean by this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can check `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer`

And probably also this `http://bytes.com/topic/c/insights/651599-handle-classes-smart-pointer`

Comment: Could mean several things, add more to your question so we get the full context.

Answer (score 2):

MatLab: [Handle classes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html) (Objects that share references with other objects)